# Sort DataFrame index that has a string and number

Tags: python, pandas

My `df` DataFrame index looks like this:

```
Com_Lag_01
Com_Lag_02
Com_Lag_03
Com_Lag_04
Com_Lag_05
Com_Lag_06
Com_Lag_07
Com_Lag_08
Com_Lag_09
Com_Lag_10
Com_Lag_101
Com_Lag_102
Com_Lag_103
...
Com_Lag_11
Com_Lag_111
Com_Lag_112
Com_Lag_113
Com_Lag_114
...
Com_Lag_12
Com_Lag_120
...
Com_Lag_13
Com_Lag_14
Com_Lag_15
```

I want to sort this index so that the numbers go from `Com_Lag_1` to `Com_Lag_120`. If I use `df.sort_index()` I will get the same thing as above. Any suggestion on how to sort this index properly?

Comment: You'd have to do a reverse find of the last '_', then cast to an int and order by this number

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One could try something like this, by performing a sort on a numbered version of the index

```
import pandas as pd
# Create a DataFrame example
df = pd.DataFrame(\
    {'Year': [1991 ,2004 ,2001 ,2009 ,1997],\
    'Age': [27 ,25 ,22 ,34 ,31],\
    },\
    index = ['Com_Lag_1' ,'Com_Lag_12' ,'Com_Lag_3' ,'Com_Lag_24' ,'Com_Lag_5'])

# Add of a column containing a numbered version of the index
df['indexNumber'] = [int(i.split('_')[-1]) for i in df.index]
# Perform sort of the rows
df.sort(['indexNumber'], ascending = [True], inplace = True)
# Deletion of the added column
df.drop('indexNumber', 1, inplace = True)
```

**Edit 2017 - V1**:

To avoid SettingWithCopyWarning:

```
df = df.assign(indexNumber=[int(i.split('_')[-1]) for i in df.index])
```

**Edit 2017 - V2 for Pandas Version 0.21.0**

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.__version__)
# Create a DataFrame example
df = pd.DataFrame(\
    {'Year': [1991 ,2004 ,2001 ,2009 ,1997],\
    'Age': [27 ,25 ,22 ,34 ,31],\
    },\
    index = ['Com_Lag_1' ,'Com_Lag_12' ,'Com_Lag_3' ,'Com_Lag_24' ,'Com_Lag_5'])

df.reindex(index=df.index.to_series().str.rsplit('_').str[-1].astype(int).sort_values().index)
```

Comment: This no loger works as .sort has been depreciated https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44123874/dataframe-object-has-no-attribute-sort . Use the answer with .sort_index instead. Also is only one line! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Answer (score 6):

Solution without new column with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by `index` of sorted `Series` :

```
a = df.index.to_series().str.rsplit('_').str[-1].astype(int).sort_values()
print (a)
Com_Lag_1      1
Com_Lag_3      3
Com_Lag_5      5
Com_Lag_12    12
Com_Lag_24    24
dtype: int32

df = df.reindex(index=a.index)
print (df)
            Age  Year
Com_Lag_1    27  1991
Com_Lag_3    22  2001
Com_Lag_5    31  1997
Com_Lag_12   25  2004
Com_Lag_24   34  2009
```

But if duplicated values is necessary add new column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(\
    {'Year': [1991 ,2004 ,2001 ,2009 ,1997],\
    'Age': [27 ,25 ,22 ,34 ,31],\
    },\
    index = ['Com_Lag_1' ,'Com_Lag_12' ,'Com_Lag_3' ,'Com_Lag_24' ,'Com_Lag_12'])

print (df)
            Age  Year
Com_Lag_1    27  1991
Com_Lag_12   25  2004
Com_Lag_3    22  2001
Com_Lag_24   34  2009
Com_Lag_12   31  1997

df['indexNumber'] = df.index.str.rsplit('_').str[-1].astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(['indexNumber']).drop('indexNumber', axis=1)
print (df)
            Age  Year
Com_Lag_1    27  1991
Com_Lag_3    22  2001
Com_Lag_12   25  2004
Com_Lag_12   31  1997
Com_Lag_24   34  2009
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is

```
    df.sort_index(key=lambda x: (x.to_series().str[8:].astype(int)), inplace=True)
```

The 8 comes from the position where the numeric values start

Comment: This is the correct approach and should be accepted, as .sort is depreciated in pandas! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html

Comment: This correct answer should be accepted