# Pandas retain index ordering

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to plot a graph but pandas keeps reordering my index (N).

I want the order to be `N= 50, 100, 200` where there are three columns for each `N` namely `2x2 3x3 4x4`

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame({"User": ["2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4","2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4","2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4"],\
                   "clm2": profit_comparison[0:len(profit_comparison)],\
                   "N": ["N=50","N=50","N=50","N=100","N=100","N=100","N=200","N=200","N=200"]})

with PdfPages('profit(n,p).pdf') as pdf:
        ax1= df1.pivot(index = "N", columns = "User", values = "clm2").plot.bar(edgecolor = "white")
        ax1.set_ylabel("Profit")
        pdf.savefig()
        plt.close()
```

Comment: You could use [seaborn.barplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html) to do the plot. You can better control the order with it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the incorrect order you're seeing is 100, 200, 50.  If that's the case, what's happening is that Pandas is sorting your index alphabetically.

In that case, you have two options:  the first is to sort the index from its numeric information, and you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493374/sort-dataframe-index-that-has-a-string-and-number) for seeing how.

The second is to just change your data to insert a zero or blank space before 50, so it falls in line:

```
profit_comparison = range (9)

f1 = pd.DataFrame (
    {
        "User": [ 
            "2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4",
            "2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4",
            "2 x 2 x 2","3 x 3 x 3", "4 x 4 x 4"
        ],
        "clm2": profit_comparison[:],
        "N": [
            "N= 50","N= 50","N= 50",
            "N=100","N=100","N=100",
            "N=200","N=200","N=200"
        ]
    },
)


ax1 = f1.pivot(
    index = "N", 
    columns = "User", 
    values = "clm2"
).plot.bar(edgecolor = "white")

ax1.set_ylabel("Profit")
```

[image]

Some additional notes:

- When within parenthesis,  you don't need the backslash to continue in the following line
- If you want to copy profit_comparison, you don't need to use `[:len(profit_comparison)]`; you can use just `profit_comparison[:]`
- If the index is still not sorted, you can use `sort_index()` on the dataframe generated by `pivot` before plotting