# Block randomization using python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply, randomized-algorithm

I have the following input table (df):

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 12 | 1 |
| B | 32 | 1 |
| C | 44 | 1 |
| D | 76 | 2 |
| E | 99 | 2 |
| F | 123 | 2 |
| G | 65 | 2 |
| H | 87 | 3 |
| I | 76 | 3 |
| J | 231 | 3 |
| k | 80 | 4 |
| l | 55 | 4 |
| m | 27 | 5 |
| n | 67 | 5 |
| o | 34 | 5 |

I would like to perform block randomization such that, it pick one value from each blocks ( one value from 1,2,3,4,5) and create that as a separate table.

The output should look something like the following:

| ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks | Groups |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B | 32 | 1 | A1 |
| E | 99 | 2 | A1 |
| I | 76 | 3 | A1 |
| l | 55 | 4 | A1 |
| m | 27 | 5 | A1 |
| A | 12 | 1 | A2 |
| F | 123 | 2 | A2 |
| k | 80 | 3 | A2 |
| m | 27 | 4 | A2 |
| n | 67 | 5 | A2 |
| C | 44 | 1 | A3 |
| H | 87 | 2 | A3 |
| J | 231 | 3 | A3 |
| n | 67 | 4 | A3 |
| o | 34 | 5 | A4 |
| D | 76 | 1 | A4 |
| G | 65 | 2 | A4 |

Randomly selected rows such that each group has all the blocks (evenly distributed).

What I tried so far?

```
df = df.groupby('blocks').apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1,random_state=1234)).reset_index(drop=True)
treatment_groups = [f"A{i}" for i in range(1, n+1)]
df['Groups'] = (df.index // n).map(dict(zip(idx, treatment_groups)))
```

This doesn't randomize according to the blocks column. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try by defining a function to generate `random` samples from each `block`:

```
def random_samples(n):
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for _, g in df.groupby('Blocks'):
            yield g.sample(n=1).assign(Groups=f'A{i}')

sampled = pd.concat(random_samples(4), ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
>>> sampled

   ColumnA  ColumnB  Blocks Groups
0        A       12       1     A1
1        D       76       2     A1
2        I       76       3     A1
3        k       80       4     A1
4        n       67       5     A1
5        C       44       1     A2
6        G       65       2     A2
7        J      231       3     A2
8        l       55       4     A2
9        m       27       5     A2
10       B       32       1     A3
11       G       65       2     A3
12       H       87       3     A3
13       l       55       4     A3
14       m       27       5     A3
15       B       32       1     A4
16       F      123       2     A4
17       I       76       3     A4
18       l       55       4     A4
19       m       27       5     A4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But, I get the following error "ValueError: No objects to concatenate". How do I deal with that?

Comment: Not sure may be something related to pandas version. What is your pandas version? Can you please check `sampled = pd.concat(list(random_samples(4)), ignore_index=True)` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `.sample(frac = 1)` returns 100% of samples which is all of them. You want the version with `.sample(n=1)`, for example if you just want one group you would do

```
df.groupby('Blocks').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1, random_state=1234))
```

to get

```
        ColumnA ColumnB Blocks
Blocks              
1   0   A       12      1
2   3   D       76      2
3   7   H       87      3
4   10  k       80      4
5   12  m       27      5
```

to get, say, 5 groups you would use `n=5` with `replace=True` (as some groups have fewer than 5 elements) and then some re-arranging:

```
df = df.groupby('Blocks').apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=5, replace = True, random_state=1234)).reset_index(drop = True)
df['Groups'] = 'A' + df.groupby('Blocks').cumcount().astype(str)
df.sort_values('Groups')
```

produces

```
    ColumnA      ColumnB    Blocks  Groups
--  ---------  ---------  --------  --------
 0  C                 44         1  A0
20  o                 34         5  A0
 5  G                 65         2  A0
15  l                 55         4  A0
10  J                231         3  A0
 1  B                 32         1  A1
21  n                 67         5  A1
 6  G                 65         2  A1
16  l                 55         4  A1
11  I                 76         3  A1
22  m                 27         5  A2
17  k                 80         4  A2
12  H                 87         3  A2
 7  F                123         2  A2
 2  A                 12         1  A2
13  H                 87         3  A3
 8  E                 99         2  A3
18  l                 55         4  A3
 3  A                 12         1  A3
23  m                 27         5  A3
14  H                 87         3  A4
 9  D                 76         2  A4
19  k                 80         4  A4
 4  A                 12         1  A4
24  m                 27         5  A4
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to start the groups from A1 and not A0?

Comment: of course, replace the relevant line with `df['Groups'] = 'A' + (df.groupby('Blocks').cumcount()+1).astype(str)`

Comment: Not sure why I get duplicate rows in each groups. For me C is present in two groups A1 and A3.

Comment: there are only three rows in block 1 so some will have to be repeated if you want 5 groups?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid those duplicates or repeats?

Comment: It is not possible to allocate three items to five groups without repeats. If you had enough rows in each block yes you can -- just replace `replace = True` with `replace = False` in `sample(...)`

Comment: That works! Whle sorting the column if I have more than 10 groups the column A11 gets sorted after A1 and A12 after A11. I.e, sorting looks like the following A1, A11, A12, A2, A3,... How can I change that? Thanks again!

Comment: something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23493374/sort-dataframe-index-that-has-a-string-and-number

Answer (score 0):

- it's truly not random,  but will group as you want
- order of source dataframe will influence order that blocks are assigned to a **Group**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ColumnA': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'], 
              'ColumnB': [12, 32, 44, 76, 99, 123, 65, 87, 76, 231, 80, 55, 27, 67, 34], 
              'Blocks': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]})

# generate a series that is "A{n}" where "n" is occurrence# of "Block"
sg = df.groupby("Blocks").apply(lambda g: pd.Series([f"A{i+1}" 
                                                for i in range(len(g))],name="Group")).explode().reset_index(drop=True)

df.join(sg)
```

|  | ColumnA | ColumnB | Blocks | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 12 | 1 | A1 |
| 1 | B | 32 | 1 | A2 |
| 2 | C | 44 | 1 | A3 |
| 3 | D | 76 | 2 | A1 |
| 4 | E | 99 | 2 | A2 |
| 5 | F | 123 | 2 | A3 |
| 6 | G | 65 | 2 | A4 |
| 7 | H | 87 | 3 | A1 |
| 8 | I | 76 | 3 | A2 |
| 9 | J | 231 | 3 | A3 |
| 10 | k | 80 | 4 | A1 |
| 11 | l | 55 | 4 | A2 |
| 12 | m | 27 | 5 | A1 |
| 13 | n | 67 | 5 | A2 |
| 14 | o | 34 | 5 | A3 |

Comment: Thank you very much! But, I get the following error: 'TypeError: explode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'column''

Comment: what version of pandas are you using> `pd.__version__`

Comment: version '1.1.2'

Comment: mostly unto date,  I'm using 1.2.1. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html was changed in 1.1.0,  haven't checked regression bugs